# Why might malware make a DNS request for an epoch time converter?

Tags: network, malware, sandbox

I am analyzing malware and I see that two executables when run in a sandbox made DNS requests for www.epochconverter.com

Why would an attacker risk detection by making a network request to epochconverter.com? What is it necessary for?

Comment: Why do you think that a DNS request for a harmless site would lead to detection? Not much is known about the details of the request but maybe the malware is just making sure that DNS works as expected as part of checking if it is in some kind of sandbox environment.

Comment: I saw that not one but two pieces of malware made the same request. I figured it would qualify as an anomaly and be noticed by anti-virus software unless other programs make similar DNS requests

Comment: The site has some code examples for converting to/from epoch, so maybe the writers just found it while searching for that and both used it for the purpose Steffan suggests since they already had it pulled up.  They could also both use the same piece of code using it for that purpose they found on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Let me put it like this,

Nowadays malware are often connected to a CNC ( Command and Conquer ) Domain, they often communicate with this domain to inform the hacker that the malware is now active and is pending for future commands to execute, this is part of the sophisticated approaches that is being used today.

- The malware enters your environment.
- Calls the CNC to make aware of his activation.
- The CNC replies with more commands to execute.
- Often the malware would use DNS Ex filtration to encrypt the data gathered and sending it to the CNC for decryption and is the hardest thing to catch without the correct tools.

The domain you have mentioned would look offline, however could be a dns server that would relocate any data posted from the pc to an XML storage space.

if the website is not accessible through a browser or through a ping test .. it could be accepting requests only from signed calls.

Comment: Welcome to the site :) 
I believe the asker was specifically curious as to why malware would reach out to a seemingly innocuous site - adding a bit of detail to your answer regarding that would make it even better!

Comment: Done :) :D I tried to illustrate as much as possible, waiting for our friends reply to go from there